# How to save frequent received data in database?

Tags: database, database-design

Me and 10 students are doing a big project where we need to receive temperature data from hardware in form av nodes, that should be uploaded and stored on a server. As we are all engineers in embedded systems and having minor database knowledge, I am turning to you guys.

I want to receive data from the nodes lets say, every 30 seconds. The table that will store that data in the database would quickly become very long if you store: [nodeId, time, temp] in a table. Do you have any suggestions how to store the data in another way?

A solution could be to store it like mentioned for a period of time and then "compromize" it somehow to a matrix of some sort? I still want to be able to reach old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One row every 30 seconds is not a lot of data. It's 2880 rows per day per node. I once designed a database which had 32 million rows added per day, every day. I haven't looked at it for a while but I know it's currently got more than 21 billion rows in it.

The only thing to bear in mind is that you need to think about how you're going to query it, and make sure it has appropriate indexes.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted to know :)